# What Java GUI framework is good for a first GUI project?

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks

The title description basically says it all. I'd like to use something that requires a *relatively* short learning curve since it is my first project and I'd like to spend at least some of it actually writing the code, not just learning how to do it, but also something that has good documentation in a way that some new bleeding edge framework probably wouldn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to do, is actually create a working program with a GUI, and you just want to do *that* I would recommend looking at the Swing GUI editor in NetBeans, as it is very easy to work with and powerful too.

There is an old demonstration floating around showing how to implement a preference panel like the one in Netscape Navigator (the predecessor to Firefox), but I cannot find it right now.

The Java tutorial trail is here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html

---

EDIT:  It appears the preference panel demo has been taken offline.  You may want to see this demo for NetBeans 6.0 instead: http://www.javalobby.org/eps/matisse-updates/

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you mean a desktop or Web GUI.

For a desktop GUI, just use Java's Swing framework. [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) is a starting point for that. Sure it's old but then again so is Swing. You could also try [The Java Swing tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/).

For a Web GUI, start with servlets/JSPs. Try [Servlets and JavaServer Pages (JSP) 1.0: A Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

Swing + [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) ^^

Answer (score 1):

I know you did say you wanted a simple and easy to learn GUI toolkit. @cletus has nailed that answer :)

But if need to look for alternatives and evaluate them before you decide how to write a GUI, check out this list of [alternatives to Swing and AWT](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/misc/80gui-generator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Swing + GroupLayout

I've been posting on these a couple of [times](http://www.google.com.mx/search?q=grouplayout+oscar-reyes+site%3Astackoverflow.com).